# How to set maximum height of a Bottom Sheet as 2/3 of screen height in Flutter

Tags: flutter, bottom-sheet

I am currently trying to make a bottom sheet as below:

```
Container(
  child: TextButton(
    onPressed: () {
      showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
              double maxHeight = (2 / 3) * MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
              return Container(
                height: constraints.maxHeight > maxHeight
                    ? maxHeight
                    : constraints.maxHeight,
                child: _BottomSheetWidget(),
              );
            },
          );
        },
        isScrollControlled: true, // Ensures the sheet is fully visible on smaller screens
      );
    },
    child: Text('Open Bottom Sheet'),
  ),
)
```

Here is my bottom sheet widget:

```
class _BottomSheetWidget extends StatelessWidget {
    const _BottomSheetWidget();

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return SafeArea(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                    [
                        // ...Some dynamic content 
                    ]
                )
            )
        )
    }
}
```

What I currently do is make the bottom sheet always have 2 / 3 screen width (even if the content height is less than 2 / 3 of the screen size, and therefore always make an empty section in the bottom sheet).

The column content is dynamic (based on the count data fetched). I want the bottom sheet height to **fit with the content if the content height is less than 2 / 3 of the screen size**. But **if the content height is more than 2 / 3 of the screen size, I want the bottom sheet height is 2 / 3 of the screen size, and therefore the bottom sheet to be scrollable**. How to do it then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Container(
  child: TextButton(
    onPressed: () {
      showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return ConstrainedBox(
                      constraints:  BoxConstraints(
                        maxHeight: (2 / 3) * MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                      ),
                child: _BottomSheetWidget(),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      );
    },
    child: Text('Open Bottom Sheet'),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer?

Comment: A constrained box is just like a container. By default, a container will inherit the height of its child but a constrained box allows you to specify a maximum height for the child. This means that the child will never be taller than the maximum height, even if its natural height is greater.



However, it is important to note that the child must be scrollable in order to use a constrained box. This is because the child may need to be taller than the maximum height in order to display all of its contents and  no to avoid constraint errors.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using LayoutBuilder, you can wrap your Modal with SizedBox

```
showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return SizedBox(
        height: (2 / 3) * MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: _BottomSheetWidget(),
      );
    },
    isScrollControlled: true, // Ensures the sheet is fully visible on smaller screens
  );
```

Don't use SingleChildScrollView as your parent in BottomSheetWidget, cause the SingleChildScrollView's height will adjust it child's height. You can move it inside the Column like this

```
  SafeArea(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: [
        /// Bottom Sheet Header or NULL
        Expanded(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: /// list widgets,
          ),
        ),
        /// Bottom Sheet Footer or NULL
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close to your desired output. Just add  `width: double.infinity`

```
Container(
    child: TextButton(
      onPressed: () {
        showModalBottomSheet(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return LayoutBuilder(
              builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                double maxHeight =
                    (2 / 3) * MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
                return SizedBox(
                  height: constraints.maxHeight > maxHeight
                      ? maxHeight
                      : constraints.maxHeight,
                  // Add this line to limit the width of the bottom sheet
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: _BottomSheetWidget(),
                  
                );
              },
            );
          },
          isScrollControlled: true,
             
        );
      },
      child: Text('Open Bottom Sheet'),
    ),
  ),
```